# Airflow Failed to fetch log file from worker

Tags: airflow

Using Airflow v2.5.1 with MySql. I started randomly receiving message "the scheduler does not appear to be running. last heartbeat was received x minutes ago". I deleted airflow-scheduler.pid file and started using "airflow scheduler -D". Now scheduled tasks are reporting message below. The log files are there. It appears to be a permissions issue where scheduler doesnt have permissions to the directories being created. I am not sure how to resolve.  Something creates the directories and log files, but scheduler doesnt have acccess to them - maybe.

```
*** Log file does not exist: /var/log/airflow/dag_id=redis/run_id=scheduled__2023-05-16T09:00:00+00:00/task_id=ssh_redis/attempt=1.log
*** Fetching from: http://plappnx-2:8793/log/dag_id=redis/run_id=scheduled__2023-05-16T09:00:00+00:00/task_id=ssh_redis/attempt=1.log
*** Failed to fetch log file from worker. Client error '404 NOT FOUND'…
```